# Angular 2/4 mapbox radius around marker

Tags: angular, typescript, mapbox, mapbox-gl

Does anyone know if it is possible to add a circle/radius around a marker using angular2-mapbox ?

I know it's not possible out of the box, but maybe it's not that big of a deal to pull out ?

Any suggestions are very welcomed.

```
<mapbox [center]="[-5.646973, 52.087483]">
<mapbox-marker
    *ngFor="let marker of map.markers"
    flyTo="16"
    [image]="marker.image"
    [coordinates]="marker.coordinates"
    [popup]="marker.popup"
    [data]="marker.data"
    (click)="markerClicked($event)">
</mapbox-marker>
```

Link to repo: [repo](https://github.com/kuflink/angular2-mapbox)

This is all they support i guess.

Answer (score 1):

A marker in mapbox is `HTML DOM`, so you're able to use CSS to style markers (i.e. not specific to mapbox angular component library).

To do this, specify in your CSS with the className `.marker` and apply the CSS styles that you require.

**example**

```
.marker {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

Assuming that you just want to make a CSS circle on its own

**circle**

```
.marker {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px
}
```

You could use pseudo-selectors to create a circle element after and position accordingly as well.

**pseudo**

```
.marker:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px
}
```

Comment: @Dragos Podaru, does this answer your question?